# Directory.GetFiles() method in C#

Tags: c#

Recently i am working on my class assignment, in which i need to get multiple
files from a directory with different extensions. 
I use this code:

```
    List<string> Extensions =new List<string>() ;
    Extensions.InsertRange(3, new string[] { "*.txt", "*.htt","*.bat"});
    FolderBrowserDialog _fBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (_fBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbPath.Text = _fBrowser.SelectedPath;
        foreach (var item in Extensions)
        {
            SearchFiles(item);    
        }

    }
```

In **SearchFile()** i use this line to search a file on base of extension:

```
     private void SearchFile(string extension)
     {
         Files = Directory.GetFiles(tbPath.Text, extension).ToList();
     }
```

If I want to search files with **.txt**, **.htt** and **.bat** extensions from a directory and if there is not any file with **.txt** extension in current directory then it cause an exception that **"Path is not legal"** but i want to continue search on base of next extension(**.htt**). 
What i can do?

Comment: What is the actual exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use try catch block

```
    List<string> Extensions =new List<string>() ;
    Extensions.InsertRange(3, new string[] { "*.txt", "*.htt","*.bat"});
    FolderBrowserDialog _fBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
    if (_fBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        tbPath.Text = _fBrowser.SelectedPath;
        foreach (var item in Extensions)
        {
            try{
                 SearchFiles(item);  
               }
            catch(Exception ex) { };
        }

    }
```

Comment: I would rather avoid using exception catches in a normal flow. Also, this code swallows any exception and may hide other problems.

Comment: yes it will prevent me from run time  exception but i want to continue with next extension.

Comment: Ok ... but this code is a slippery slide of ignoring the original problem, which is not understood. It is low health code. The MSDN documentation says that the method ought to return an empty list and does not list an exception like you describe. There is something else wrong here I think.

Comment: Yes i get rid of this...... there was another problem which imposing exception for illegal path.....  I was using another check on path for its validity which was the main source of this exception......  after removing that check my code is free from this exception.....

Answer (score 3):

You can use something like this:

```
var extensions = new string[] { ".txt", ".htt", ".bat" };

var foundFiles = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*.*")
    .Where(file => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(file), StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```